# how to break a line or space in between two rows of the html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to give space or break between two rows, so that my page will looks good.

if you look my code i had given many empty rows and column to make a space between two rows in the table.

Please say any other proper way to give space between two rows.

here is my sample code:

```
<form:form name="form" method="post" modelAttribute="Abatch">

 <table>
<tr>
    <td>Please enter your comments</td>
    <td><form:textarea id="textarea" style="width:150%;height:150%" path="Comments" size="255" readonly="false" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr>     
   <td><input id="button1"   type="submit" name="submit" value="Approve"/></td>
   <td><input id="button4"  type="submit" name="submit" value="Reject"/></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the style tag to add padding to the row? You should only really use Tables for tabular data, as they were intended for.

Comment: CSS is your friend.  It looks like you're using `<table>` simply to provide layout.  That is usually not a good idea.  If you must/will use a table, use CSS styles on it to achieve the desired layout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the CSS box model:

margin values do not apply to table rows and table cells
See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

padding and border values do not apply to table rows but apply to table cells
See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties

A quick fix is to add padding to the top of the row that you want to separate.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/caXsZ/

Sample HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr class="row1">
        <td>Row One - 1</td>
        <td>Row One - 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row2">
        <td>Row Two - 1</td>
        <td>Row Two - 2</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
tr.row2 td {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

If you want to style borders around your table cells, you may need to add wrappers around the content and apply borders depending on the design details.

Comment: its not taking margin.? wts the solution for this

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Row 1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
        <!--you just need a space in a row-->
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Row 2
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: A simple solution with out any styling

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to give spacing for tables is to use cellpadding and cellspacing e.g.

```
<table cellpadding="4">
```

or using css :

```
<style type='text/css'>    
  table{ border-collapse: separate; }
  table td { border-spacing: 1em; }
</style>
```

Comment: This does not work, CSS ignores margins and padding on table rows.

Answer (score 4):

```
border spacing attribute has to be specified in CSS

table
    {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:10px 0px;
    }
```

The above code set 10px spacing between the rows and 0px spacing between the columns

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved like this.

`<tr>
    <td> <br> </td> <!--The br tag did what i was looking for -->
</tr>`

Answer (score 1):

Set the `margin`attribute for a `<tr>` tag:

```
<tr style="margin-top:10px;"></tr>
```

Or make the entire table with this style:

```
<style>
    table tr {
        margin-top: 10px;
    } 

    table tr:first-child {
       margin-top: 0px; !important
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This does not work, CSS ignores margins and padding on table rows.

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me is defining css properties at column level and defining colspan as the number of columns in the table

Html -

```
<tr class="border_bottom">
    <td colspan="6"></td>
</tr>
```

CSS -

```
tr.border_bottom td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    color: #707070;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```