# How to add space in between two tr or rows - CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

How to add space in between two TR or table rows using CSS?

I have a table and in that table I have multiple rows.

```
+--------+----------------------------------+
| COL 1  |               COL 2              |
|        |                                  |
|        |                                  |
|        |                                  |
+--------+----------------------------------+
|            Transparent Space              |
+--------+----------------------------------+
| COL 1  |               COL 2              |
|        |                                  |
+--------+----------------------------------+
|            Transparent Space              |
+--------+----------------------------------+
```

In my table I have variable height of COL1 contents, but COL2 has fixed height content.

**I have created JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/w5aLf2vc/

In above JSFiddle I need to display 30px bottom spacing for each row and that spacing should be transparent or it should be grey as background. Also I am creating this table using `ng-repeat` and $scope array.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009591/how-to-break-a-line-or-space-in-between-two-rows-of-the-html-table

Comment: @XYZ: main problem is that my contents in the table has bg color as white and I need to display this blank space or div that is holding this table. If we have bg color to TD then we see the issue.

Comment: can you solve  this by  making empty rows in between ??

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps :

```
<body>
    <div style="background:gray;">
        <table style="border:0;">
            <tr>
                <td class="my-td-left">TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1
                </td>
                <td class="my-td-right">TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Style 1: Background changed -->
            <tr style="height: 10px;">
                <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #fff;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="my-td-left">TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2
                </td>
                <td class="my-td-right">TD2 TD2 TD2 </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Style 2: No background change -->
            <tr style="height: 10px;"></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="my-td-left">TD3 TD3 TD3</td>
                <td class="my-td-right">TD3 TD3 TD3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/w5aLf2vc/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this:

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td{
  padding:5px;
}
.my-td-left{
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;  
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
 }

.my-td-right{
  background: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;  
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}
tr:nth-child(2n) td{ 
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:gray;">

  <table style="border:0;">
    <tr>
      <td class="my-td-left">TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1</td>
      <td class="my-td-right">TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1 TD1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="space">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="my-td-left">TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 TD2 </td>
      <td class="my-td-right">TD2 TD2 TD2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="space">
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="my-td-left">TD3 TD3 TD3</td>
      <td class="my-td-right">TD3 TD3 TD3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS' `nth-child(even)` to select every 2nd `tr`.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve use this, use cellspacing attribute like given below:

```
<table cellspacing="5"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```