# Replacing div with table gives multiple <br> tags before the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal dialog with a div (divSInfo) that I'm replacing with a dynamically generated table when a button is clicked.

The table does appear, but I get 7 < br> tags that appear before the table.  Looking in the console, the table generated doesn't include those tags.

Anyone any idea how I can eliminate the rogue < br> tags?

Here is the modal dialog:

```
<div id="modalViewS" class="modal fade" role="dialog">       
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">View</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <p>If any of this information is incorrect, please delete the entry and add it again</p>
                        <div id="divSInfo"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div style="text-align: right;">
                        <button id="btnViewSOK" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server">OK</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm getting the table using the following:

```
var getJSON = function () {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('post', "SomePage.aspx?REQ=myvars", true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var status = xhr.status;
        if (status == 200) {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        } else {
            reject(status);
        }
    };
    var reqjson = JSON.stringify({
        VarID: asiid
    });

    xhr.send(reqjson);
});
};

getJSON().then(function (data) {
console.log(data);
var a = data.TableData.replace("<br/>", "");
console.log(a);
$('#divSInfo').replaceWith(a);
}, function (status) {
    //alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

The console reports that "a" returns as:

```
<table class="table table-bordered"><tr class="tableheader_bg"><th>Question</th><th>Answer</th></tr><tr><td>S. Description</td><td>fvbbnvfn</tr><tr><td>S. Length</td><td>7 Seconds</tr><br/><tr><td>Loss?</td><td>No</tr><br/><tr><td>Warning?</td><td>No</tr><br/><tr><td>S Onset</td><td>7</tr><br/><tr><td>Occurs</td><td>Out of Sleep</tr><br/><tr><td>Has S resulted in injury?</td><td>No</tr><br/><tr><td>S Classification</td><td>Impaired</tr></table>
```

But the actual page renders like this:

```
<div>
<p>If any of this information is incorrect, please delete the entry and add it again</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr class="tableheader_bg"><th>Question</th><th>Answer</th></tr><tr><td>S. Description</td><td>fvbbnvfn</td></tr><tr><td>S. Length</td><td>7 Seconds</td></tr><tr><td>Loss?</td><td>No</td></tr><tr><td>Warning?</td><td>No</td></tr><tr><td>S Onset</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>Occurs</td><td>Out of Sleep</td></tr><tr><td>Has S. resulted in injury?</td><td>No</td></tr><tr><td>S. Classification</td><td>Impaired</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: break tags don't just magically appear, they're being created by something.

Comment: I don't disagree.. but I can't see what is creating them in the code I posted.  I don't have anything else happening on there.. button click.. run code.. <br> tags appear..

Comment: Question for the mods: Am I posting something poorly here?  I explained the issue, provided code snippets, but my post is knocked down to -3 - not sure what I should be doing differently

Comment: the code you’ve provided can’t produce the results you claim to have. the question is unclear

Comment: how is it unclear?

console.log(a);  returns the table string as shown above.

$('#divSInfo').replaceWith(a);  sets that string to the div

the rendered page is as displayed?

Also, the rendered page has <tbody> added which I certainly didn't add - it is using bootstrap 3 - not sure if that has an impact on that or not. I wouldn't have thought so, but if i knew the answer, I wouldn't be asking

Comment: tbody was added by the browser, that’s normal.

Comment: it’s very likely that the break tags were already there

Comment: but they aren't.. I showed the modal dialogs html.. no <br> tags.

Comment: one of your two claims are simply false, break tags don’t just magically materialize from nothing.

Comment: I didn't come on here to lie.. how would that help me?  I showed the code, I showed html, I asked the question.  If you have something constructive to add that I can look up to help debug it, great. if not, thanks for your attempt.

Comment: i’m not accusing you of lieing, i just think you are misinterpreting results. unfortunately we aren’t there to look at the results directly, and there isn’t any code in the question that we could take and recreate your problem with.

Comment: for example, comment out the replacewith line. do the break tags remain? prove it by providing the result of an innerHTML call

Comment: Yes.  changed    //var a = data.TableData.replace("<br/>", "");    to var a = data.TableData;  the line breaks remain, the console shows the table but not the <br> tags  as shown here:   https://i.imgur.com/7jHodtE.png

Comment: Great, that proves the problem isn’t caused by the code provided.

Comment: a = the table without any line breaks.   if I remove the replaceWith(a), the div does not get overwritten with the table and the line breaks aren't there   https://i.imgur.com/VemD5cT.png

Comment: and if you replace a with hello world?

Comment: <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="divSzContainer">
                            <p>If any of this information is incorrect, please delete the entry and add it again</p>
                            hello world
                        </div>
                    </div>

Comment: i think i see the problem. are those break tags i see between your table rows? hard to tell on mobile, it’s blurry

Comment: stripping those out from my input between the rows fixed the issue.  Would the same mechanism that added the <tbody> have shifted those from within the <table> tag to outside it?

Comment: yes, they were in invalid, so the browser fixed it

Comment: ok, that explains it.  if you want to post that into the answer I'll mark as complete.  thanks

Comment: I should have scrolled through the html code sample you provided, i completely missed that. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the browser comes across html that it can't interpret, weird things may occur. In your case, you have html between a few of your table rows that don't belong, so instead of losing that html the browser moved it up the tree until it was valid, in this case just above the table.

I assume those are there to provide spacing, but spacing [should instead be added with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009591/how-to-break-a-line-or-space-in-between-two-rows-of-the-html-table).

Comment: Similar problem for <br> after <tr> in a table. All <br> are moved above the table.